# Storing data from file into array then reading specific line and column from file in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, fstream

I have a text file (students.txt) like this:

> StudentID StudentName StudentName2 StudentMarks
>
> 100 Justin Smith 94
>
> 101 David Mason 79
>
> 102 James Stewart 88
>
> 103 Carl Brown 79

(The list goes on like this until ID 300)

I will write a program such that when a StudentID is entered, it searches its values in StudentID and outputs its corresponding StudentName and StudentName2 and StudentMarks.

My approach:
I used fstream to open the file.
I want to create an array [4] for each column.

Issues:

1. I cannot 'separate' the columns into arrays. (for storing & fetching)
2. I cannot make it to ignore the 1st line of the text(i.e the titles) which would not be a problem but since I declared the 4th column (StudentMarks) as integer, but the title is a string so I think it is better to make it to ignore the 1st line (?)
3. I cannot input a 3rd name for a student (If I input StudentName3 for some, the others' StudentMarks will appear in the place of their marks.) 
   [For now, I tried: concatenating StudentName2 and the 3rd name by using '_' e.g Brown_Smith]

I couldve created a simple array and make it to read and output every line one by one, but in some scenario, I do not want to output the StudentID, that's why I want to separate it into columns.

Im a c++ beginner.
Do you think that my approach to create an array for the 4 columns is appropriate?
Comments appreciated a lot ~

Comment: It looks like you have different data types here (int for `StudentId`, string for `StudentName`, etc...), so storing it all in a single array would mean having to store it all as strings. That'll mean a lot of conversions later for comparing or doing math with `StudentMarks`. Instead, I'd suggest using a struct for each student. Can you show what you've written so far so we can help tell you what you're doing wrong?

Comment: @scohe001 is correct, use a `vector<struct>`. Don't separate by columns but rather by lines. You can easily tokenize each line into its separate elements. For 2. use a delimiter such as `#` to mark a comment.  This way you can have them all over your file.